# how to sort in asc in nested array object based on condition using javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, arrays, object

I have array of object in which i need to sort based on condition using javascript.

I need to sort the others list based on tariffId but in the order 7201, 7202, 7203, 7205, 7204

means always 7204 is the last.rest can be in asc order

```
var arrobj = [
  {id:1, others: [ {place: "IN", tariffId:7201}, {place: "IN", tariffId:7204}, {place: "IN", tariffId:7203} ] }
  {id:1, others: [ {place: "IN", tariffId:7201}, {place: "IN", tariffId:7204}, {place: "IN", tariffId:7205} ] }
  {id:1, others: [ {place: "IN", tariffId:7202}, {place: "IN", tariffId:7204}, {place: "IN", tariffId:7201} ] }
]
```

Expected output

```
 {id:1, others: [ {place: "IN", tariffId:7201}, {place: "IN", tariffId:7203}, {place: "IN", tariffId:7204} ] }
  {id:1, others: [ {place: "IN", tariffId:7201}, {place: "IN", tariffId:7205}, {place: "IN", tariffId:7204} ] }
  {id:1, others: [ {place: "IN", tariffId:7201}, {place: "IN", tariffId:7202}, {place: "IN", tariffId:7204} ] }
]
```

Tried

```
var result = arrobj.map(e =>
 e.others.sort((a,b)=> a-b).map(i => i))
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You had it almost already, just need to move 7204 to the end of the new sorted array.

```js
const IN = "IN"; //needed for running this example

let arrobj = [
  {id:1, others: [ {place: IN, tariffId:7201}, {place: IN, tariffId:7204}, {place: IN, tariffId:7203} ] },
  {id:1, others: [ {place: IN, tariffId:7201}, {place: IN, tariffId:7204}, {place: IN, tariffId:7205} ] },
  {id:1, others: [ {place: IN, tariffId:7202}, {place: IN, tariffId:7204}, {place: IN, tariffId:7201} ] }
]

arrobj.map(elem =>
  elem.others.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.tariffId === 7204) return 1; // Move 'a' to the end
    if (b.tariffId === 7204) return -1; // Move 'b' to the end
    return a.tariffId - b.tariffId; // Sort the rest normally
  })
)

console.log(arrobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this, but here a simple solution might be to transform 7204 into a large number during sort.

eg.

```js
var arrobj = [
    { id: 1, others: [{ place: "IN", tariffId: 7201 }, { place: "IN", tariffId: 7204 }, { place: "IN", tariffId: 7203 }] },
    { id: 1, others: [{ place: "IN", tariffId: 7201 }, { place: "IN", tariffId: 7204 }, { place: "IN", tariffId: 7205 }] },
    { id: 1, others: [{ place: "IN", tariffId: 7202 }, { place: "IN", tariffId: 7204 }, { place: "IN", tariffId: 7201 }] }
]

const last7204 = v => v === 7204 ? 10000000 : v;

var result = arrobj.map(e => {
    e.others = e.others.sort((a, b) => last7204(a.tariffId) - last7204(b.tariffId))
    return e
})

console.log(result)
```

A little side note:  your using `map` here, but you might not realise your still mutating the original array.  If you do `console.log(arrobj)` you will see what I mean.  A small fix for this would be to do ->

```
var result = arrobj.map(e => {
    return [...e.others].sort((a, b) => last7204(a.tariffId) - last7204(b.tariffId))
})
```